# Can you help me identify this vehicle outside the VAB?

Tags: nasa, history, identify-this-object

I found this photo of a house being transported off of Kennedy Space Center property sometime in the 1960s/early 1970s. We managed to track down where the house was moved from/to, but one thing that has stuck with me is what is the vehicle that is towing the house?

[image]

[image]

I've tried reverse image searching, but just got many pictures of armoured vehicles.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: (Where was the house being moved from/to?)

Comment: I don't know it's exact original position, but somewhere near Roberts Road (https://www.google.com/maps/@28.5419362,-80.6659214,4104m/data=!3m1!1e3) and is now out near Scotsmoor :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like a motor scraper. Probably an Allis Chalmers 260E or similar.

[image]

[Contractor](https://contractormag.co.nz/classic-machines/allis-chalmers-260e/) magazine

Comment: Thank you! That must be it. It looks much more ominous in bnw :D

Comment: You're welcome. The odd thing is, if it's towing the house, it's being driven in reverse. I don't actually see a connection (chain/cable) between the house and the scraper though.

Comment: @HarryStranger to me, the context threw me off. I've seen these construction vehicles a zillion times. But having the VAB in the background, and that it's pulling a house, made me try and think if NASA modified something for the Shuttle and the house pulling was just a PR stunt to show it's capability. Good question!

Comment: @BruceWayne I'm not sure it's towing the house. It's probably just parked there.

Comment: @OrganicMarble - [...oh](https://i.imgur.com/etdHe1F.gif). I misread that photo a few ways then didn't I? ...I will show myself out :P

Comment: @BruceWayne I'm not sure! But it seems the scraper is backwards for towing.  The OP thought it was towing it.

Comment: @bruceWayne If they had the scrapers for road construction it would be a not unreasonable device to tow with, they would be setup for massive low speed torque and cause less damage to asphalt than a tracked vehicle. Scrapers were probably present regardless of the actual tow just for leveling the path the house moved along.

Comment: @BruceWayne from the site I found the image "Roy Roberts home passing the Vertical Assembly Building of the Kennedy Space Center while being moved from the Orsino town site in the 1960's." https://www.ghosttowns.com/states/fl/orsino.html

Comment: @OrganicMarble it's a shame there's only the one image, but from context I assumed it was being towed by that vehicle

Comment: @HarryStranger I totally get it. the angle makes it looks like some strange machine with a blacked-out windshield and a slanted hood - but it's really the back of the pan.